# JQuery click same button with different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I have a button with class name **test-button test-button--check**. After clicking **test-button--check** it should do something and be replaced by class **test-button--reset**

For **test-button--reset** I want to write another function, but It doesn't work. Because, the previous function executes again.

```
$(".test-button--check").on("click", function() {
  alert("Check is clicked");
  $(this).removeClass("test-button--check").addClass("test-button--reset");
});

$(".test-button--reset").on("click", function() {
  alert("Reset is clicked");
  $(this).removeClass("test-button--reset").addClass("test-button--check");
});
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code to your question - then we can maybe tell you why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code inside the document.ready in this way

```
$(".test-button--check .test-button--reset").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var obj=$(this);
   if($(obj).hasClass('test-button--check')){
       alert("Check is clicked");
       $(this).removeClass("test-button--check").addClass("test-button--reset");
   }
   if($(obj).hasClass('test-button--reset')){
       alert("Reset is clicked");
       $(this).removeClass("test-button--reset").addClass("test-button--check");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using .off() to remove an event handler, in this case, it is click.

Should be something like this:

```
$('.test-button.test-button--reset').off().click(function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
var check = function checkFunc() {
alert('Check is clicked!');
$(this).addClass('test-button--reset').removeClass('test-button--check');
$('.test-button--reset').unbind('click',check);
$('.test-button--reset').bind('click',reset);
}
var reset = function resetFunc() {
alert('Reset is clicked!');
$(this).addClass('test-button--check').removeClass('test-button--reset');
$('.test-button--check').unbind('click',reset);
$('.test-button--check').bind('click',check);
}
$('.test-button--check').bind('click',check);
```

Using bind and unbind